# Receiving Error: Invalid arguments while using TextEditorEdit.insert

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension that connects to an API, downloads some text, creates a file, inserts the text to this file and opens on an editor.

For that I am using the code snippet below:

```ts
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(file_uri).then(function(doc){
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc).then(function(editor){
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(editor);
        console.log("Editor..."+editor);
        editor.edit(function(editBuilder){
            editBuilder.insert(0, template_payload);
            //myEditBuilder(editBuilder, template_payload);
        }).then(function(result){vscode.window.showInformationMessage(result);});
        //editor.edit(function(editBuilder){myEditBuilder(editBuilder, template_payload);});
    });
});
```

When I ran my code I receive the following error and stack trace:

```
rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: Invalid arguments
extensionHostProcess.js:730
stack trace: Error: Invalid arguments
    at new g (/Applications/Visual Studio Code 3.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:329:834)
    at new g (/Applications/Visual Studio Code 3.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:327:254)
    at h.insert (/Applications/Visual Studio Code 3.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:443:123)
    at /Users/igor.simoes/VSCode_extension/appdvelocitytemplateupdater/extension.js:166:18
    at f.edit (/Applications/Visual Studio Code 3.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:448:510)
    at /Users/igor.simoes/VSCode_extension/appdvelocitytemplateupdater/extension.js:165:12
```

On my code line 165 is my `editor.edit()` command, and it does not seem to be missing arguments.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the value of `template_payload`?

Comment: It is the string "Payload"... when it is on production this will be a document containing HTML download through the API....

Comment: Hm, are you writing this in pure JavaScript instead of TypeScript? Upon pasting the code into VSCode, I immediately get an error about your usage of `editor` in the `showInformationMessage()` call: https://i.imgur.com/x44MruJ.png

Comment: I am writting in pure JavaScript. I will upload the extension to git so you can access the full source code.

Comment: Please see the full code on this repo.This version is the one presenting the problem: https://dev.azure.com/igorsimoes/_git/VSCode%20Velocity%20Template%20Tool%20for%20AppDynamics

Comment: My point was that the error that the TypeScript compiler shows is likely the reason why you're running into an exception: you're passing something that has an incorrect type to `showInformationMessage`.

Answer (score 1):

You have

`editBuilder.insert(0, template_payload);`

but `editBuilder` is a `TextEditorEdit` whose `insert` function is:

`insert(location: Position, value: string): void`

this your first argument was `0`, that is not a `Position` which is a `(line: number, character: number)` so `new Position(0,0)` is what you wanted.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditorEdit